# extract the cartesian form out of a span of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

i need to get the cartesian form out of a span of vector:

$span((-1,3,1);(1,2,0);(3,1,-1))$

i've tried to parametrized it but,

- simply multiplying 3 parameter to the vectors and set the coordinates equal to those
  feels like an hell
- i've tried row reducing , but then i don't know how to interpret the results:

$\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&1\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$

so the x = -a+c ; y = 0 ; z = 1b+2c

is the equation y = 0?
because x and z are linear indipendent? ( the dimension is clearly 2 so i expect 2 free variable and 1 equation..)

are there any other way of getting the cartesian form ?

Thanks!

Comment: The result you obtained by Gauss elimination tells you that, since span is invariant under Gauss' transformations, your initial span is equal to $span((-1,01)(0,1,2))$, so it's a plane.

Comment: but i don't think the equation is true, since just by taking 1 vector of the span it doesn't satisfy the equation...

Comment: The equation is not $y=0$. Let $P_1=(-1,0,1)$ and $P_2=(0,1,2)$. Let $X=(x,y,z)$. Then $X$ is in the plane if and only if the set $X,P_1,P_2$  is a set of linearly dependent vectors. Therefore you just have to put them in a matrix and impose its determinant to be $0$, and you get the equation of the plane.

Answer (score 0):

$\left| 
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & 3 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 0 \\
 3 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right| = 0$

Therefore, the triangle is degenerate and only defines a line whose Cartesian form would be, e.g., $t (\{-1,3,1\}-\{1,2,0\})+\{3,1,-1\}$ or $\{3-2 t,t+1,t-1\}$.